# Как сделать поиск?

Tags: php, html, yii, yii2

Как отправить данные наподобие html тега `a` но через форму? Необходимо передать значение переменной `page=1`

```
<a href="www.nostname/web/index.php?r=test/access/index&page=1">
```

Я пытаюсь:

```
`<form action="www.nostname/web/index.php?r=test/access/index&page=1" method="get">
           Поиск:  <input type="text" name="page">
          <p><input type="submit"></p>
</form>`
```

**Но**, вместо того что бы переходило по этому адресу :

`http://nostname/web/index.php?r=test/access/index&page=1`

переходит по этому ,если я ввожу в импут формы 3.

`http://nostname/web/index.php?page=3`

Comment: ну в форме есть атрибут `action`,  туда передаешь ссылку `<form method="www.nostname/web/index.php?r=test/access/index&page=1">..`, и когда форма будет отправлена, форма обратится по этой ссылке на сервер.

Comment: @Василий Барбашев Это не так. Сейчас я покажу куда она обращается.

Comment: @Василий Барбашев Я обновил свой вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С обновленным вопросом, решение такое:

```
<form action="www.nostname/web/index.php" method="get">
    Поиск:  <input type="text" name="page">
    <input type="hidden" name="r" value="test/access/index">
    <p><input type="submit"></p>
</form>
```

В итоге переходит по ссылке:

```
www.nostname/web/index.php?page=5&r=test%2Faccess%2Findex
```

На сервере: `$_GET`

```
Array
(
    [page] => 5
    [r] => test/access/index
)
```

Comment: Не работает . у вас значение `page ` в переди стоит  нужно в самом конце что бы было. пример -  `www.nostname/web/index.php?r=test/access/index&page=1`

Comment: эм, местами поменяй элементы тогда, просто `hidden` поле поставь выше. Не ужели сложно догадаться?

Comment: Я это сделал но не работает. Потому что значение там кодируется из-за неправильного адресса

Comment: что кодируется? ничего не понял. Тут ничего не может кодироваться. Я вам написал что сервер возвращает на `$_GET`. Там нет ничего закодированного

Comment: Урааа...Заработало... Да всё правильно.. Спасибо я вас люлю!!!!